# Predicate Calculus: Clarification on Switching Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Consider X={9, 10, 15}, Y={2,3}. Let Q(x,y): y divides x
Then, is ∀x∃y Q(x,y) ≡ ∃y∀x Q(x,y)?

I answered yes, ∀x∃y Q(x,y) ≡ ∃y∀x Q(x,y).

Am I correct? If not, then why are these quantified statements not equal?

Comment: $\exists y\,\forall x\, Q(x,y)$ is not true

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  The order of [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)#Order_of_quantifiers_(nesting)) is critical to meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\exists y\,\forall x\, Q(x,y)$ would mean there is an element of $Y$ that divides $9, 10, $ and $15$.

But $2$ does not divide $9$, and $3$ does not divide $10$, and there is no other element of $Y$.

Therefore, it is not true that $\exists y\,\forall x\, Q(x,y)$, even though it is true that $\forall x\, \exists y\,Q(x,y)$

(take $3$ for $9$ and $15$, and $2$ for $10$); these quantified statements are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! This clears it for me. I should be using {and} for all instances of ∀ instead of {or}.